# Python - using raw_input() to search a text document

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a simple script that a user can enter what he/she wants to search in a specified txt file. If the word they searching is found then print it to a new text file. This is what I got so far.

```
import re
import os

os.chdir("C:\Python 2016 Training")
patterns = open("rtr.txt", "r")

what_directory_am_i_in = os.getcwd() 

print what_directory_am_i_in

search = raw_input("What you looking for? ")

for line in patterns:
    re.findall("(.*)search(.*)",  line)
    fo = open("test", "wb")             
    fo.write(line)
    fo.close
```

This successfully creates a file called test, but the output is nothing close to what word was entered into the search variable.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have not read a file

```
patterns = open("rtr.txt", "r")
```

this is a file object and not the content of file, to read the file contents you need to use

```
patterns.readlines()
```

secondly, `re.findall` returns a list of matched strings, so you would want to store that. You regex is also not correct as pointed by Hani, It should be

```
matched = re.findall("(.*)" + search + "(.*)",  line)
```

rather it should be :

if you want the complete line

```
matched = re.findall(".*" + search + ".*",  line)
```

or simply

```
matched = line if search in line else None
```

Thirdly, you don't need to keep opening your output file in the for loop. You are overwriting your file everytime in the loop so it will capture only the last result. Also remember to call the close method on the files.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much guys. As you can probably tell im very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

you are searching here for all lines that has "search" word in it

you need to get the lines that has the text you entered in the shell

so  change this line

```
re.findall("(.*)search(.*)",  line)
```

to

```
re.findall("(.*)"+search+"(.*)",  line)
```